# Whats the best way to sort a dataset into groups by using a facial recognition algorithm that compares only 2 images at a time?

Tags: algorithms, graphs, sorting

I have a facial recognition algorithm that compares two images A and B and returns the likelihood that they match.

I also have 50,000 images, and I would like to sort these images into groups.

Here's the immediate way I thought of to do this:

1. Start with image 0, compare it to all 49,999 images. Store the similarities in an array
2. Move on to image 1, compare it to 49,998 images (skip img_0). Store the similarities in an array

At the end of it all I'm left with a `verified_list`of images that matched, and I can basically feed them into a network to combine them, ie if I have a `verified_list` like so:

`[[1,2,3],[2,5,6],[8,9]]` (`verified_list` is the same length as the number of images, so `verified_list[1]` contains references all the images that image_1 matches with)

then the network graph combines them into:

`[[1,2,3,5,6], [8,9]`

Indicating I have two groups.

Obviously this is a huge amount of processing, I think it equates to: nCr(50000,2), some huge number!

Is there a faster way to sort my dataset into groups?

Comment: This question smells XY problem.

Comment: @Apass.Jack Yeah, I'm just gonna delete the bottom half and leave it a bit more open

Comment: You say "sort into groups" but what do you mean by that?  What properties do you want the groups to have?  Do you know in advance how many groups you want?  Have you read about clustering algorithms? If not, maybe that would be helpful to you.  I still don't see why there'd be any hope to avoid doing all pairwise comparisons, though.

Comment: Also, it's possible that if we were given knowledge of how the algorithm for comparing two faces works, it might be possible to speed up the process.

Comment: @D.W. The aim is to sort into groups by person. The algorithm is a neural net that converts a face into a vector. the comparison occurs by taking the euclidean distance between the two vectors.

The algorithm is designed so that different individuals will have vectors that are further apart, while the same individual will have vectors that are closer together

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it appears you actually have vectors over $\mathbb{R}^n$, one vector per face, and you want to group the vectors, using $L_2$ distance (Euclidean distance) to measure similarity.

There are a number of techniques for this.  See data structures for nearest neighbor search (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_neighbor_search).  I would suggest that locality sensitive hashing might be a promising choice for your situation.  You could also look into clustering algorithms (though they will probably still require nearest neighbor search as one step of their working).